# Restrict if not a proper file using OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#

Hi all i have written a small code to open a particular text file. Now on open file dialog under the file name a drop down is displaying some file names if i select a file from that and click on ok i would like to display an error message as wrong file selected.

My code to open particular text file is as follows

```
openFileDialog1.FileName = string.Empty;
strFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
strFilePath = strFilePath + "\\ACH";
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = strFilePath;
openFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.txt)|FileHeader*.txt";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            using (myStream)
            {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
                //FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                txtFileHeader.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString(); ;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

If any modifications to be done please let me know.

---

I just write my code as follows as i did not find any declaration like var

```
            string compareType = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (fileName.StartsWith("FileHeader", compareType)
                && extension.Equals(".txt", compareType))
```

I am Getting the errors as

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.StringComparison' to 'string'

Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'string.StartsWith(string, System.StringComparison)' has some invalid arguments

Error   4   Argument '2': cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.StringComparison'

Error   5   Static member 'string.Equals(string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

So can any one please what to do...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - how do you identify a "wrong" file?

Comment: Are you asking how to read the names in the drop-down auto-complete menu that pops up in the file dialog?

Comment: using this code, I get an Error 1 - The name 'myStream' does not exist in the current context. Where does the mystream variable get declared?

Comment: @Brian Declare Stream myStream;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?  You could also use regex, but I don't have VS on this machine and felt like being lazy.

I'd add, while you could file off the incorrect file name.  It may be better to add an `All Files (*.*)|*.*` to file filter list and allow the user to select anything he might like.  Then allow the application to fail during the file read if they select the wrong file.  This would be more of an expected use case that would match how most other applications function.

```
Stream myStream;
openFileDialog1.FileName = string.Empty; 
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"..\..\ACH"; 
openFileDialog1.Filter = "FileHeader (FileHeader*.txt)|FileHeader*.txt"; 
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
    var compareType = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    if (fileName.StartsWith("FileHeader", compareType)
        && extension.Equals(".txt", compareType))
    {
        try 
        { 
            using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) 
            { 
                // Insert code to read the stream here. 
                //FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName; 
                txtFileHeader.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. " +
                            "Original error: " + ex.Message); 
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invaild File Type Selected");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error as 

The best overloaded method match for 'string.StartsWith(string, System.StringComparison)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: The only mistake I found was `MessageBox.Box`.  Could you update your example with your changes?

Comment: if (fileName.StartsWith("FileHeader", compareType)
        && extension.Equals(".txt", compareType))

At this point i am getting the error 

and i just changed the variables as follows

string compareType = Convert.ToString( StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);

Comment: using this code, I get an Error 1 - The name 'myStream' does not exist in the current context. Where does the mystream variable get declared??

Comment: I added the line - "Stream myStream;" so that the variable would be declared, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Final Answer and the correct one

```
         if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StringComparison compareType = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (fileName.StartsWith("CCD_BatchHeader", compareType) || fileName.StartsWith("PPD_BatchHeader", compareType)
                && extension.Equals(".txt", compareType))
                try
                {

                    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        using (myStream)
                        {

                            txtBatch.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
                            myStream.Close();
                        }
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("InvalidFile");
            }
```

Comment: what's the difference b/w this answer and Matthew Whited's?

Comment: @Brian check the code twice you will find the difference as per the code he given i write for my own